# Advance Replace in insert scripts

Tags: sql, oracle, function, replaceall

I have below 2 insert statements which i took the export from sql developer from dev environment. I have delete those records from dev afterwards. Now i want to run this insert statement again in dev because those are my back up but i am getting error as virtual column which is ORD_DAYID cannot be used inside insert script. So i want to exclude this column and also the respective values using replace function or any tools which i dont know. I didnt know previously that i have virtual column for this table. I would like to know is there any tool or function where i can select ORD_DAYID and also the respective values get selected and then i can delete those and then i can be able to run this insert statement again in test enviornment.

P.S i have mentioned only 2 sample insert statements but there are 1000 insert statements. So its very difficult to manually delete this ORD_DAYID from this insert statements with respective values.

```
Insert into test_ord (IS_GRP,ORD_DAYID,REF_CAMPA_CODE) values (1,20150813,null);
Insert into test_ord (IS_GRP,ORD_DAYID,REF_CAMPA_CODE) values (1,20150828,null);
```

Comment: Why would the dev environment look different from the backup?

Comment: Just use vi ,sed,awk , Editplus or Notepad++ or anything that is available to selectively delete those from your sql file. It is meaningless to do that in sql. And in sql developer can't you select only the real columns before exporting into an insert statement?

Comment: @Gordon its not different its the same environment. Kaushik as i mentioned in my question i didnt know previously that i have virtual column for this table otherwise i could have exlcuded those column. I used Notepad++ but it doenst select the respective values for column which i have selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your INSERT statements using regular expressions, in an editor such as Notepad++.

So to change this ...

```
Insert into test_ord (IS_GRP,ORD_DAYID,REF_CAMPA_CODE) values (1,20150813,null);
```

... into this ...

```
Insert into test_ord (IS_GRP,REF_CAMPA_CODE) values (1,null);
```

You need a **search** pattern of:

```
Insert into test_ord \(IS_GRP,ORD_DAYID,REF_CAMPA_CODE\) values \(([0-9]+),([0-9]+),null\);
```

and a **replace** pattern of:

```
Insert into test_ord \(IS_GRP,REF_CAMPA_CODE\) values \(\1,null\);
```

Obviously you will need to refine the search pattern to cater for all the different values of IS_GRP, and REF_CAMPA_CODE in your 1000 statements.

---

> " is there any way where we can count the place of column and value and replace it with null"

No. The snag with virtual columns is that they cannot be referenced in INSERT or UPDATE statements. So you need to totally exclude it from the projection.

> "i am not able to find those option in notepad++"

Really? Search and replace is not an exotic option:

- From the menu: `Search > Find > Replace [tab]` (or `[ctrl]+h`)
- As the *search mode* select the `regular expression` radio button

[image: Notepad++ regex search'n'replace]

Comment: i am not able to find those option in notepad++. Is it possible for you to show in notepad++ what you want to say ? And i also dont understood about refine the search pattern ? I am thinking is there any way where we can count the place of column and value and replace it with null

Answer (score 0):

1. create an auxiliary table without virtual columns.
2. Restore your data to this auxiliary table.
3. Transfer the data from the auxiliary table to the original table.

```
    -- this is your table
    create table mytab(A number, b number, s as (a+b));
    --fill it with data
    insert into mytab(a,b) values(1,1);
    insert into mytab(a,b) values(1,2);
    insert into mytab(a,b) values(2,1);
    insert into mytab(a,b) values(2,2);
    commit;
    -- check its content
    select * from mytab;
    -- now delete the rows
    delete from mytab;
    commit;

    -- restore your data
    --------------------

    -- create a table similar the table you want to restore
    --   but the virtual colums as regular columns.
    create table ctas as 
        select * from mytab where 1!=0;

    -- insert your backup data
    insert into ctas(a,b,s) values(1,1,2);
    insert into ctas(a,b,s) values(1,2,3);
    insert into ctas(a,b,s) values(2,1,3);
    insert into ctas(a,b,s) values(2,2,4);
    commit;

    -- transfer the data to the table you want to restore
    insert into mytab(a,b) select a,b from ctas;
```